# Memory mapped address in C (how to dereference)

Tags: c, dereference

I want to pretend that an array in C is an area of memory in a microprocessor, so I can compile some code on a PC.  I've written a small program to try to get the syntax correct, but the program won't run, it either crashes or won't compile when I change the way I access the variable - it's late and I can't see why.  What is wrong with this please?

```
// original code in microprocessor header that I need to change if I compile on the host
// BASE is simply a hex value that is later used as an address or a hex value
#define BASE (0x0000)
// used later in header like this (cannot change the way this is done)
#define OFFSET 0x0001
#define PERIPHERAL (BASE + OFFSET)
// also used like (also cannot change):
uint32_t var = PERIPHERAL | HEXMASK;

// here is how I intend to replace the uC specific code
// replace the BASE DEFINE with the next 2 lines of code:

// instead of writing to memory location, write to array of bytes instead, so declare it:    
uint8_t BASE_memory[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
// define BASE as hex value that can be used as drop-in replacement in either of the 2 uses shown above
#define BASE ((uint32_t)(BASE_memory))

// now test usage
// access contents of BASE_memory[0]
printf("contents of  BASE_memory[0] == %02x\n", *((uint32_t *)(BASE)));


// now I want to access PERIPHERAL, the second element of the array, i.e. BASE_memory[1]
printf("contents of  BASE_memory[1] == %02x\n", *((uint32_t *)(PERIPHERAL)));
```

Comment: You seem to be playing fast an loose with pointer arithmetic.  When you try to access BASE[1], should that get bytes 4 through 8 or bytes 1 through 5?  Neither appears to have been allocated, which is a potential (but unlikely) fault, however the second has the potential for triggering an unaligned access fault on some architectures but not others.  Why (uint32_t *) ?

Comment: Sorry, typing on an iPad now and typed BASE instead of BASE_memory, now edited.  Microprocessor is 32 bit, but reference to microprocessor memory map in datasheets is in bytes, hence uint32_t as it's easier to see what's I'm doing in the hardware code.  I basically would like to be able to use the (BASE + hex offset) construction in my PC code to allow unit testing on PC (don't have to wade through huge headers from manufacturer and change). Thanks so much for looking at this!

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish an 8 bit access or a 32 bit one?  Because right now you are doing an unaligned (in either first case or second or both) 32 bit access, and in the 2nd case that includes to unallocated (at least for that purpose) memory, since you are accessing the 5th byte of a 4 byte array...

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thanks. I'm such an idiot, of course. When I increase the array, it runs ok, and I can access via either 32 or 8 bit access in the printfs. I get warnings about casting for #define BASE ((uint32_t)(BASE_memory))

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, much appreciated - there were a number of issues at play here, starting with the points you mentioned.  When I followed them up with changing uint32_t to uintptr_t, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on a 64-bit system.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t BASE_memory[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int func1()
{
    return *(uint32_t *) (uint32_t) BASE_memory;
}

int func2()
{
    return *(uint32_t *) (uintptr_t) BASE_memory;
}
```

Here's the assembly output for `func1`:

```
leaq    _BASE_memory(%rip), %rax
movl    %eax, %eax
movl    (%rax), %eax
```

Here's the assembly for `func2`:

```
movl    _BASE_memory(%rip), %eax
```

You can see that if you cast the address to `uint32_t`, then there's an extra step where the high bits are set to zero.  The address is then wrong, and you get a segmentation fault.  That's why you use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` instead of `uint32_t`.

Comment: Good point, that could be a problem, too.  One shouldn't force an address into a type too small to potentially hold it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this - SO is great, I didn't know about uintptr_t until now!  There were actually a number of issues here: the code had compiled correctly after I followed @ChrisStratton's suggestions and removed the initial errors, but then crashed on running.  Changing the relevant datatypes to uintptr_t solved it.  For future reference, in case anyone else is interested, I've put details on our company blog of dual targeting the STM32F4 Discovery board for building on a Mac, allowing unit testing on a host computer: http://blog.blackkitetechnology.com/?p=58